# passing variables from one class to another in wxpython

Tags: python, python-2.7, wxpython

I have a problem with passing textCtrl data from one class to another in wxpython.  I tried using the instance method of passing variables but if I use **init**_function it is only relevant at the start of the program and doesn't take into account any changes to the text control box after the initial start. Tried the Update() or Refresh() and it didn't work either.

Here is the code simplified.

```
class DropTarget(wx.DropTarget):


     def __init__(self,textCtrl, *args, **kwargs):
          super(DropTarget, self).__init__( *args, **kwargs)
          self.tc2=kwargs["tc2"]
          print self.tc2


class Frame(wx.Frame):

     def __init__(self, parent, tc2):
     self.tc2 = wx.TextCtrl(self, -1, size=(100, -1),pos = (170,60))#part number

def main():

     ex = wx.App()
     frame = Frame(None, None)
     frame.Show()
     b = DropTarget(None, kwarg['tc2'])
     ex.MainLoop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The following way of passing the variable gives me a keyerror.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't the most elegant solution to the problem, but I had a similar issue.  If you dump your text to a temporary text file, you can pick it back up whenever you want.  So it would be something like this:

```
tmpFile = open("temp.txt",'w')
tmpFile.write(self.tc2.GetValue())
tmpFile.close()

#when you want the string back in the next class
tmpFile = open("temp.txt",'r')
string = tmpFile.read()
tmpFile.close()
os.system("del temp.txt")    #This just removes the file to clean it up, you'll need to import os if you want to do this
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import wx
class DropTarget(wx.DropTarget):


     def __init__(self,textCtrl, *args, **kwargs):
          self.tc2 = kwargs.pop('tc2',None) #remove tc2 as it is not a valid keyword for wx.DropTarget
          super(DropTarget, self).__init__( *args, **kwargs)

          print self.tc2


class Frame(wx.Frame):

     def __init__(self, parent, tc2):
         #initialize the frame
         super(Frame,self).__init__(None,-1,"some title")
         self.tc2 = wx.TextCtrl(self, -1, size=(100, -1),pos = (170,60))#part number

def main():

     ex = wx.App(redirect=False)
     frame = Frame(None, None)
     frame.Show()
     #this is how you pass a keyword argument
     b = DropTarget(frame,tc2="something")
     ex.MainLoop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

there were at least a few errors in your code ... it at least makes the frame now